# Problem to connect to an AWS postgres instance via a bastion host via SSHTunnel in python

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS postgres instance and an AWS ec2 instance (running as bastion host). From my local machine I want to connect to that AWS postgres instance via a python script. But it's not working (see below).

My setup is:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                    ('internet-adress-of-the-basion-host', 22),
                    ssh_private_key=r"the-private-key.pem",
                    ssh_username="ec2-user",
                    local_bind_address=('localhost', 6543),
                    remote_bind_address=('internet-adress-of-the-postgres-server', 5432)) as server:

                server.start()
                print("server connected")

                self.conpostgres = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', port=server.local_bind_port, database="the-database",
                                                    user="the-user", password="the-password")
```

I can sucessfully connect via the sshtunnel (the "server connected" messages is printed to the console), but I get an ERROR in the when excecuting psycopg2.connect.

The connect ERROR is:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6543?
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "the-user"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "the-user", database "the-database", SSL off
```

Two remarks:

```
1.) In the line "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x"". Here the "x.x.x.x" address is NOT localhost (127.0.0.1). It's a normal ip4 internet address. But I have no idea where this address is coming from!
2.) !!!! With the exact same configuration mentioned above I can successfully connect to the  database via the database tool built in IntelliJ Idea. So there is a way to connect to the postgres server without changing pg_hba.conf. So maybe I have to configure the tunnel differently?
```

Comment: It sounds like your SSH Tunnel is working just fine. It just needs authentication to be setup via `pg_hba.conf`. Somebody will be able to assist you with that, but you might need your question to highlight `pg_hba.conf` as the problem rather than the SSH Tunnel.

Comment: thx, when connecting to the database via a SQL-Query-Tool (also with configuring an ssh tunnel), I can connect.

Comment: Check the server's log file to see why authentication failed.

Comment: That error is being reported by the database server so x.x.x.x would be its opinion on the IP address of the bastion host.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking Programming Q&A. You are more likely to get help with `pg_hba.conf` by asking at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/